# facebook tab iframe specific page open

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-apps, facebook-iframe, static-html

i just want to ask, i have a Facebook tab , which opens a small website like an frame in this tab  , how can i add a link to the tab for a specific page in the frame "" lets say for example tab frame have 3 pages "home , about us , contact us" how can i add a share button which redirect me to this tab and i find contact us opened.

knowing that using static frame app .

and this is my code

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : '535262793177723',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : 'http://bridgestone.thesocialclinic-server.com/', // Channel file for x-domain comms
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  function mohammad(){FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}




</script>
<iframe src="http://bridgestone.thesocialclinic-server.com" scrolling="no" style="border:none;" width="100%" height="2000" onload="mohammad()"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After A lot of testing and checking , the result was that i was using static HTML application to add a new  tab and get some benefit from fan gate etc... 
but that was the problem , after creating the tab in the normal way without any application it worked like a charm.

thank you cdbconcepts for your help .

Answer (score 0):

You would need `app_data` URL parameter, and use a link such as `http://www.facebook.com/[page_name]/?sk=app_[app_id]&app_data=[specific_page]`

Where `app_data` will be in the 'signed_request'. So you set `app_data=page3`, and check the parsed signed request value of `app_data`, and perform a redirect within your app.

Comment: Every time you access the app via the Tab URL, signed_request will not be empty as FB makes a POST when it initially accesses your app URL. If you navigate around your app, you will lose it unless you pass it around using GET/POST (Saving signed request in a session is not reliable since so many browsers block 3rd party cookies).